# Get next empty element inside a array, while iterating

Tags: php, arrays

I want to insert a element inside a array, but not overwrite any existing elements:

```
$to_insert = 25;
$elem  = 'new';

$arr = array(
  5 => 'abc',
 10 => 'def',
 12 => 'xyz', 
 25 => 'dontoverwrite',
 30 => 'fff',
);

foreach($arr as $index => $val){
  if($to_insert == $index){
    // here get next free index, in this case would be 26;
    $arr[$the_free_index] = $elem;
  }   
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a simple loop that starts from `$to_insert` and increases the loop variable until it finds a value that does not already exist as a key in `$arr`. So you can use `for` and [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
for($i = $to_insert; array_key_exists($i, $arr); ++$i) ;
$arr[$i] = $elem;
```

This will correctly insert the element both when the `$to_insert` key exists and when it does not.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/m3Afr)**.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will find the next index not in use, starting at `$to_insert`:

```
$to_insert = 25;
$elem = 'new';

for($i = $to_insert; ; $i++)
{
   if(!isset($arr[$i]))
   {
      $arr[$i] = $elem;
      break;
   }
}
```